# Continuity and integration relationship

Tags: functions, continuity, indefinite-integrals

Is there a relation between the integral of a function and its continuity? For example, $\sin x^2$ is continuous but not integrable.

Comment: It's certainly integrable: do you mean that its antiderivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Every continuous function on a closed interval is integrable.

Comment: The integral is always continuous, if the function is continuous then the integral is differentiable maybe you should look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Answer (score 0):

$$x\mapsto sin (x^2)$$ is continuous at $\Bbb R $, thus it is integrable at any  compact $[a,x] $.

Its integrale function is defined by $$F : x\mapsto \int_0^x \sin (t^2)dt $$

it can't be expressed easily. You can call it for example $$Sin_2 (x). $$

Like $\int_1^x\frac {dt}{t} $ is called $\ln (x) $.

Comment: What about $S(x)$, which usually denotes the Fresnel sine ?